# Prepend each variadic macro argument with a name of a function parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I have a macro that is used inside of a class definition for defining as_tuple() member functions.

```
#define DEFINE_AS_TUPLE(...) \
    auto as_tuple() const \
    { \
        return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
    auto as_tuple() \
    { \
        return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); \
    }
```

but I'd like to have a macro for defining class_as_tuple functions outside of a class. In common it should look like this:

```
#define DEFINE_AS_TUPLE_OUTSIDE_OF_CLASS(ClassName, ...) \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(const ClassName & val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(ClassName & val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
```

but it is not clear how to prepend VA_ARGS with 'val.' in std::tie() call.

To make the question more clear I provided an example of how my first macro is used:

```
class B
{
public:

    B() : m_set{ 0, 1, 2 }, m_v{3, 4}
    {
    }

    DEFINE_AS_TUPLE(m_set, m_v, m_u8, m_b)

private:

    std::set<int> m_set;
    std::vector<int> m_v;

    uint8_t m_u8 = 25;

    bool m_b = true;
};
```

but I also need:

```
DEFINE_AS_TUPLE_OUTSIDE_OF_CLASS(B, m_set, m_v, m_u8, m_b)
```

Comment: Can't you template it?

Comment: I'd advise trying to find a solution *not* requiring the use of macros in the first place (even if a bit more typing may be involved). Macros are *evil*.

Comment: @ JesperJuhl it would be great to avoid macros. But how?

Comment: C++ is sometime verbose. Just type those functions. Eventually, helper classes/functions may help, but you'll have to type them.

Comment: Have you considered deriving your classes from a template class that provides these members and tuple acessors?

Comment: For complex preprocessor tasks, I either refer to or use Boost::Preprocessor.

Comment: @Mawg just to template sounds too broad, what did you mean exactly?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Clarify please, how base class can help here?

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I do not have boost.

Comment: You could download Boost. The Preprocessor library is, of course, header only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pragmatic approach would be to type out (or possibly generate) a macro for each number of parameters you care about. Given that you might not need to "tuplify" more than e.g. 10 members and that this pattern is apparently common enough in your code to warrant a macro like this, writing them out by hand may be the easiest way. For example:

```
#define DEFINE_AS_TUPLE_OUTSIDE_OF_CLASS_2(ClassName, a, b) \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(const ClassName& val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(val.a, val.b); \
    } \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(ClassName& val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(val.a, val.b); \
    }

#define DEFINE_AS_TUPLE_OUTSIDE_OF_CLASS_3(ClassName, a, b, c) \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(const ClassName& val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(val.a, val.b, val.c); \
    } \
    inline auto class_as_tuple(ClassName& val) \
    { \
        return std::tie(val.a, val.b, val.c); \
    }
```

However, this [does not work](https://godbolt.org/g/HbvTZD) in your given example as all the members are private. You'd have to make these into `friend` functions, so you'd need a macro for that, in which case you could just write `class_as_tuple` using `val.as_tuple()`...